# Resize static image file in Google App Engine

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

I have uploaded a static image (e.g., at location: /images/no-image.jpg) as part of my code that gets used as the default image when there is no specific image available (basically of the type: "no image for this item")

Just realized that this image may have to be served at more than one size (I have uploaded -- and want to upload -- just one size).

How do I resize this image using Google's Images Service?

If I use the example shown at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/#Java_Transforming_images_in_Java , that means having to read the file, apply the transform, then write a servlet to serve up the file... which seems like a lot of work. Is there an easier way?

Will it be easier to just upload the image to the BlobStore :-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your CSS file:

```
.placeholder {
    background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Now, when you don't have a specific image to serve, simply add "placeholder" class to your container element.

Remember to make this image cacheable.

Comment: Does `background-size:contain` mean that the image will be resized (by the browser?) to fit in its container while maintaining aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes, it will fit within the container without changing the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the `getServingUrl` function for serving and resizing images for two reasons:

1. simpler to use. to resize, you just append parameters to the image url
2. It will significantly reduce the load off your instances, since the images are served without a servlet, but with google magic

Comment: I am using `getServingUrl` for images that are uploaded per item (and therefore stored in the Blobstore), but the idea behind using a static image (uploaded as part of the `war`) for items that don't have an image uploaded for them was to serve up the same image every time, increasing efficiency.

Comment: you can load the same image when it's in the blobstore. IMO it's best to have the all the images in the blobstore, it will probably save you code

Comment: Isnt it posible to serve a single size (the largest) and just display it resized on client-side? (Forced dom element width/height)

Comment: @ZigMandel This is largely what Andrei Volgin is suggesting in another answer. This brings us to the compute-cycles (in case of resizing) vs. bandwidth-consumed (serving up largest image & letting CSS resize) debate: which is cheaper?